# Can't seem to float div next to min/max width fluid div

Tags: html, css

I have a div here,

```
#leftBanner {
height: 100%;
background-color: #CCC;
width: 22%;
min-width: 245px;
max-width: 355px;
float: left;
}
```

that doesn't seem to want to let any div float next to it. I know I can ditch the min/max or give it a static width to resolve the issue, but I'd like to try to find a solution before I give up.

Here's a fiddle of my experimenting.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m4FB/)

I plan on covering this with a fixed navigation bar of the same width and 100% height. Right now I am just trying to get a div floated next to it that does not slide under when filled with content or overlap the leftBanner.  I have no problem with manually filling content or entering a height for each page as long as i can get it to work.

Strangely enough, Dreamweaver's code view gives me exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't work when published.

[image]

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a container around the content, and flaot left and right, and dropping the min and max width:

http://jsfiddle.net/2m4FB/18/

```
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
#container{width:100%;
max-width:970px;}
#leftBanner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 22%;
float:left;
}
#mainContent {
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: .3;
    float:right;
    width:78%;
}
```

Comment: Notice the #container, this is now a div wrapped around both the maincontent and left nav bar. Setting a max-width on the container will force a max width on the contained elements.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you figure out how this play together a bit as you proceed. [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/A792K/)

The min max sizes may not be needed unless you are making this responsive.  If that is the case I can shed some light on that.

```
#leftBanner {
    width:22%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#mainContent {
    width:78%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
```